# Call WCF webservice using Windows Authentication from an Azure App Service

Tags: c#, azure, wcf, windows-authentication, azure-app-service-envrmnt

_ Azure newbie alert _ I have a WCF web service (deployed on prem) that uses windows authentication. I just built an App Service on Azure that among other things it needs to retrieve data from this web service. I don't have control over the authentication mode it uses nor can I change it, so is there any way at all to configure my App Service to use Azure AD and authenticate using a windows account (same account used on Azure portal)?

On a side note, I communicate with the WCF service on prem through a hybrid connection on the App Service. Not sure if that makes any difference

Comment: Do you have Active Directory in Azure?

Comment: @Baskar yes, it's sync'ed up with the coorporate AD

Comment: Are you using service bus relay to connect to your WCF Service

Comment: @Baskar, no. Hybrid Connection

Comment: You should be able to consume the service by using the dns name in hybrid connection.  This is one I was able to find. https://mindovermessaging.com/2014/07/14/using-azure-hybrid-connections-to-consume-an-on-premise-wcf-service-from-the-cloud/